# OS Page aligned allocation in Perl

Tags: perl, mmap, ioctl

A driver exposes its API by ioctl interface.

The argument for the ioctl call is a memory buffer that its address
must aligned to OS page size.

For example the allocation in C would call valloc (or posix_memalign)

Simple Perl allocation of the buffer like this:

```
 $buffer = "\0" x  BUFFER_SIZE ;
```

is not enough since most probably the starting address of the scalar
wont be aligned to OS page size.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Note: I convert the buffer to the C address like this:

```
 my $c_address = unpack('Q', pack('P', $buffer));
```

Thanks!
Eyal

Comment: Just allocate `BUFFER_SIZE * 2`, then you can find a page of memory within the buffer.

Comment: You might also be able to use the (ancient) Mmap module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, but going by the book, you can use the `IO::AIO` module, which has a `IO::AIO::mmap` function. Basically, you'd do something like this (untested):

```
    use IO::AIO

    IO::AIO::mmap
          my $buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, IO::AIO::PROT_READ | IO::AIO::PROT_WRITE,
          IO::AIO::MAP_PRIVATE | IO::AIO::MAP_ANONYMOUS, undef
       or die "mmap failure: $!";
```

The `$buffer` will be unmapped automatically when you `undef` it or it goes out of scope, or you can use `IO::AIO::munmap $buffer`.

You can also doing it yourself in other ways by aligning some larger memory allocation, but you at least would need to query the page size, so a pure-perl solution cannot be done portably without the help of modules, and/or wasting memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The mmap solutions by IO::AIO or maybe File::Map or Sys::Mmap are good and are the preferred way of course. However in my production environment I can't (for now) add modules to the perl installation (locally compiled) and none of those modules present in the installation. So I guess the only way for me is to allocate some more memory and calculate the aligned address.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that solves the problem without using mmap.

Basically the code does what posix_memalign() does.

```
# Required for 'syscall' below
#
require 'syscall.ph';

use strict;
use warnings;

# Linux / unix specific
#
my $PAGE_SIZE = `getconf PAGE_SIZE`;

# Arg = size of requested buffer
#
# return = 1. allocated buffer
#          2. C address of allocated buffer
#          3. Offset for aligned buffer
#
# Code is not portable and tested on x86_64 only.
#
sub valloc
{
    my ($size, $ALIGN) = @_;

    $ALIGN = $PAGE_SIZE
        unless ($ALIGN);

    my $buffer = "\0" x ($size + $ALIGN - 1);

    my $address = unpack('Q', pack('p', $buffer));
    my $aligned_address = (($address + $ALIGN - 1) & (-$ALIGN));
    my $offset = $aligned_address - $address;

    return ($buffer, $address, $offset);
}
#-------------------------------------------------------------

# Example to a function that accepts C address
#
sub cat
{
    my ($path) = @_;

    open (my $fh, '<', $path) || die "$path: $!\n";

    my $size = -s $fh;
    my ($buffer, $address, $offset) = valloc($size);
    syscall(&SYS_read, fileno($fh), $address + $offset, $size);
    close $fh;

    return substr($buffer, $offset, $size);
}
#-------------------------------------------------------------

my $content = cat(__FILE__);
print $content;
```

Comment: Haven't run your script, but getconf isn't defined aynwhere, and it's not coming from syscall.ph.

Comment: Also, it's not quite what posix memalign does - your example overallocates memory by a factor of two, something that posix_memalign does not (in actual implementations) do. Of course, this is quite acceptable in many situations.

Comment: It is not a factor of two, just an additional size of a page. it is (size + ALIGNMENT - 1).
syscall.ph is needed for the cat() function example. Not part of valloc implementation.

Comment: Indeed - I wrongly assumed the alignment is the size of the buffer in the question, but it's not.